# Implementing authorize.net in android

Tags: java, android, authorize.net

I want to develop an application which does payment processing through authorize.net

But everytime I get unknown error.

First I fill all the textboxes and use these values on a button click event.
My code is:

```
txtAmount=Double.parseDouble(Amount.getText().toString());
txtFName = FName.getText().toString();
txtLName=LName.getText().toString();
txtAddress=Address.getText().toString();
txtCity=City.getText().toString();
txtState=State.getText().toString();
txtzipcode=zipcode.getText().toString();
txtEmail=Email.getText().toString();
txtCreditCard=CreditCard.getText().toString();
txtCVV2=CVV2.getText().toString(); 

drpMonth=selectedmonth;
drpYear=selectedyear;
date= drpMonth.concat(drpYear);

try {
    URL post_url = new URL("https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll");

    Hashtable post_values = new Hashtable();

    // the API Login ID and Transaction Key must be replaced with valid values
    post_values.put ("x_login", "8SX5gkJb46g");
    post_values.put ("x_tran_key", "8Wx295Gr4hd9Y5kd");

    post_values.put ("x_version", "3.1");
    post_values.put ("x_delim_data", "TRUE");
    post_values.put ("x_delim_char", "|");
    post_values.put ("x_relay_response", "FALSE");

    post_values.put ("x_type", "AUTH_CAPTURE");
    post_values.put ("x_method", "CC");
    post_values.put ("x_card_num", txtCreditCard);
    post_values.put ("x_exp_date", date);

    post_values.put ("x_amount", txtAmount);
    post_values.put ("x_description", "Sample Transaction");

    post_values.put ("x_first_name",txtFName);
    post_values.put ("x_last_name",txtLName);
    post_values.put ("x_address", txtAddress);
    post_values.put ("x_city", txtCity);
    post_values.put ("x_state",txtState);
    post_values.put ("x_zip", txtzipcode);
    post_values.put ("x_email", txtEmail);
    // Additional fields can be added here as outlined in the AIM integration
    // guide at: http://developer.authorize.net

    // This section takes the input fields and converts them to the proper format
    // for an http post.  For example: "x_login=username&x_tran_key=a1B2c3D4"

    StringBuffer post_string = new StringBuffer();
    Enumeration keys = post_values.keys();
    while( keys.hasMoreElements() ) {
        String key = URLEncoder.encode(keys.nextElement().toString(),"UTF-8");
        String value = URLEncoder.encode(post_values.get(key).toString(),"UTF-8");
        post_string.append(key + "=" + value + "&");
    }

    // Open a URLConnection to the specified post url
    URLConnection connection = post_url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // this line is not necessarily required but fixes a bug with some servers
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // submit the post_string and close the connection


    DataOutputStream requestObject = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    requestObject.write(post_string.toString().getBytes());
    requestObject.flush();
    requestObject.close();

    // process and read the gateway response
    BufferedReader rawResponse = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    String responseData = rawResponse.readLine();
    rawResponse.close();                         // no more data

    // split the response into an array
    String [] responses = responseData.split("|");

    // The results are output to the screen in the form of an html numbered list.

    for(Iterator iter=Arrays.asList(responses).iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        result="\n"+ iter.next() +"&nbsp";
        tv.setText(result);
        //out.println("<LI>" + iter.next() + "&nbsp;</LI>");
    }

    setContentView(tv);
} catch(Exception e) {
    tv.setText(e.getMessage());
    setContentView(tv);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

through setContentView I am showing my splited result and I get only unknown error exception. No other description is shown. Is my method wrong or there is any other method to implement payment processing ?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide more information about the error you're getting.  Is it merely "unknown error", or is there an error code or anything further information?  Also, why are you calling `setContentView` from within a `Button` onClick method?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your code :) I got new idea form your code to implement authorize.net in android I have no idea what you faced error but when I tried to use post url for integration I faced one error and I have added "x_market_type"  in my code and I got the result

 `post_values.put ("x_market_type", "2");`

I have also integrated Sample code which authorize.net provide, but for my custom requirement your code helps me lot.

If you need any help than post comment. :)

Comment: Hi Bhavin, I need to integrate authrozed.net in my app .. how to integrate using login id and transaction key ? I tried to sent the details but i got E0003 error .

Comment: I didn't get anything in response result, I just got "onPostExecute: 
                                                                  |&nbsp"

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you use the HTTPClient instead as shown in this example
[How do I make an http request using cookies on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678630/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-using-cookies-on-android)

From what I can see in your code:

1. This section will given an extra & at the end

   > ```
   > while( keys.hasMoreElements() ) {
   > String key = URLEncoder.encode(keys.nextElement().toString(),"UTF-8");
   > String value = URLEncoder.encode(post_values.get(key).toString(),"UTF-8");
   > post_string.append(key + "=" + value + "&");
   > ```
   >
   > }
2. You read only a single line of what has been returned by the server. Even though the content might be placed in one line, the HTTP headers will span several lines

> ```
> String responseData = rawResponse.readLine();
> ```

3. You use the default user-agent request header which may not be accepted by the server

If you want to try fixing your current code, I recommend you debug it or throw in some log statements (which you can view with for example the aLogCat application)

Answer (score 0):

//Authorize.net android implementation using volley post. this might help you and rashmi thanks for the code and bhavin for the error help

```
final String txtAmount=totalprice.getText().toString();
        final String txtFName = first_name;
        final String txtLName=last_name;
        final String txtAddress=address_1;
        final String txtCity=city;
        final String txtState=state;
        final String txtzipcode=postcode;
        final String txtEmail=email;
        final String txtCreditCard=CardNumber;
        String txtCVV2=Cvv;

        String drpMonth=Month;
        String drpYear=Year;
        final String date= drpMonth.concat(drpYear);



        String url = Uri.parse("https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll").buildUpon()
                .build().toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e("====", response);
                        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("====", error.toString());
                        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> post_values = new HashMap<String, String>();
                post_values.put ("x_login", "8RtP63yV");
                post_values.put ("x_tran_key", "9A4a59AThQh4c6wG");

                post_values.put ("x_version", "3.1");
                post_values.put ("x_delim_data", "TRUE");
                post_values.put ("x_delim_char", "|");
                post_values.put ("x_relay_response", "FALSE");
                post_values.put ("x_market_type", "2");

                post_values.put ("x_type", "AUTH_CAPTURE");
                post_values.put ("x_method", "CC");
                post_values.put ("x_card_num", txtCreditCard);
                post_values.put ("x_exp_date", date);

                post_values.put ("x_amount", txtAmount);
                post_values.put ("x_description", "Sample Transaction");

                post_values.put ("x_first_name",txtFName);
                post_values.put ("x_last_name",txtLName);
                post_values.put ("x_address", txtAddress);
                post_values.put ("x_city", txtCity);
                post_values.put ("x_state",txtState);
                post_values.put ("x_zip", txtzipcode);
                post_values.put ("x_email", txtEmail);
                return post_values;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```