# Android integration, Where to put the API Login ID & Transaction Key in Authorized.Net SDK

Tags: android, authorize.net

I am currently integrating the Authorize.net SDK on the android platform.
I am able to successfully send my transactions with the test account.
However, I would like to skip the "Login / Password" screen when the transaction
is processed. Note that I am not currently using the  "API Login ID & Transaction Key"
but the login and password of my test account. So the real question is :

Where to put the API Login ID & Transaction Key inside the code.

```
authNetObj = AuthNet
            .getInstance(Environment.PRODUCTION,
                    R.layout.authnet_mobile_merchant_auth_dialog,
                    R.id.authnet_loginid_edit, R.id.authnet_password_edit,
                    R.id.authnet_auth_cancel_button,
                    R.id.authnet_auth_login_button);
```

//NO  API Login ID & Transaction Key  args ?

```
     Intent authNetIntent = authNetObj.createAIMAuthCaptureIntent(this,
     refId, totalAmount, creditCard, order, customer, shippingAddress,
     shippingCharges, emailReceipt, merchantDefinedFields);
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi Patel Deval I need help for authorize.net integration in android. Have you integrated it?? I have integrated sample but need some help from your side. Your question is older so that I ask for help :)

Comment: Hi Deval there is no need API Login ID & Transaction Key for android. I have integrated this:) I also want to skip step of merchant login. Please post if you solved this. Thanks

Comment: @BhavinChauhan : how did you done it within test account.getting problem with test account.Logcat displays getMerchant() all the time.so need your help for this.

Comment: @Biginner I have used post API of authorize.net

Comment: @BhavinChauhan : i am following this https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android/ and what about you?

Comment: @Biginner I have used it above but I have to login with Id and password, Which I do not want. So i used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310375/implementing-authorize-net-in-android

Comment: @BhavinChauhan : can you share your sample project with me?

Comment: @Biginner sure I will, Just give me Your email, Will sent it after an hour!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50871/discussion-between-biginner-and-bhavin-chauhan)

Comment: hello ,have you got solution of it?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, it is not recommended to store your login ID and Transaction Key on a mobile device. So, the SDKs are not designed to support that method of authentication.