# Using Cookies across Activities when using HttpClient

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpclient

I'm trying a simple app to read in the HTML of a website, and tranform it to create an easily readable UI in Android (This is an exersize in learning android, not to make a useable app). The problem I'm having is persisting a users session across Activities and then using the session in a `HttpClient` once recalled.

I would like to do this "Correctly", the recommended approach seem to be to use `CookieManager`. I've had problems with this however - I cannot seem to find the "Correct" way to take a `Cookie` from the `CookieManager` and use it in a later instantiation of `HttpClient` in a seperate Activities.

When using a `CookieManager` I can save the `Cookie` and the `Cookie` is then in scope in other Activities (See code snippet 2). I haven't found how to use this later (See code snippet 3) when requesting a page.

Enough talking, here is some code. First my login action and Cookie storage:

```
private OnClickListener loginActionListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        EditText usernameTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
        EditText passwordTextView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        String username = usernameTextView.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordTextView.getText().toString();

        try {
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(URI);                
            HttpParams params   = new BasicHttpParams();

            params.setParameter("mode", "login");
            params.setParameter("autologin", true);
            params.setParameter("username", username);
            params.setParameter("password", password);
            postMethod.setParams(params);

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response        = httpClient.execute(postMethod);
            List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

            if(cookies != null)
            {
                for(Cookie cookie : cookies)
                {
                    String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + cookie.getDomain();                        
                    CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);  
                }
            }
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), IndexAction.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {...}
}
```

The startup Activity which decides wether to make the user login or go to the index is below. You can see from this code that the cookie is in scope and can be read:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);

    if(CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(URI) == null)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginAction.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IndexAction.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

But from my code to read the Index page I'm hoping you can suggest what i'm missing:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);

    try
    {
            HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(URI_INDEX);  

            HttpParams params   = new BasicHttpParams();                        
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 30000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30000);

            // This code results in a ClassCastException, I'm assuming i've found a red herring with this solution.
            // HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();    
            // localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(URI));

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            HttpResponse response        = httpClient.execute(getMethod);

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() > 299 && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 400)
            {
                // Not logged in doesn't give a redirect response. Very annoying.
            }

            final char[] buffer = new char[0x10000];
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            Reader in = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
            int read = 0;
            while (read>=0)
            {
              read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
              if (read>0) {
                out.append(buffer, 0, read);
              }
            }

            String returnString = out.toString();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {...}
}
```

The `HttpClient` on `execute(getMethod)` isn't using the Cookie (double checked this in debug) to pull back the page. It would be great if someone could fill this hole in my knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

When commented code is added back in (with the `httpClient.execute(getMethod)` method change to `httpClient.execute(getMethod, localContext)`) this strack trace is produced - Assumedly because i'm filling the attribute `ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE` with a `Cookie` `String` rather than a `CookieStore`:

```
*org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:88), org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:290), org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:160), org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:401)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555), org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487), 
com.testapp.site.name.IndexAction.onCreate(IndexAction.java:47), 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047), 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611), 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663), 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117), 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931), 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99), 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123), 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683), 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method), 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507), 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839), 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597), 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*
```

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace of your exception? This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652850/android-webview-cookie-problem

Comment: And possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678630/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-using-cookies-on-android

Comment: It doesn't help that httpClient.getCookieStore().addCookie(Cookie) needs a Cookie object and CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(URI) returns a string. Cookie is an Interface and I don't know what subtype to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(As promised a solution to this. I still don't like it and feel like I'm missing out on the "Correct" way of doing this but, it works.)

You can use the `CookieManager` to register your cookies (and therefore make these cookies available between apps) with the following code:

Saving cookies into the `CookieManager`:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

if(cookies != null)
{
    for(Cookie cookie : cookies)
    {
        String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + cookie.getDomain();                        
        CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(cookie.getDomain(), cookieString);  
    }
}
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
```

Checking for cookies on specified domain:
`if(CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(URI_FOR_DOMAIN)`

To reconstruct values for HttpClient:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
String[] keyValueSets = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(URI_FOR_DOMAIN).split(";");
for(String cookie : keyValueSets)
{
    String[] keyValue = cookie.split("=");
    String key = keyValue[0];
    String value = "";
    if(keyValue.length>1) value = keyValue[1];
    httpClient.getCookieStore().addCookie(new BasicClientCookie(key, value));
}
```

Comment: its important to also set the domain of the new BasicClientCookie(key, value) so better something like BasicClientCookie c = new BasicClientCookie(key, value);
   c.setDomain(URI_FOR_DOMAIN);
   httpClient.getCookieStore().addCookie(c);

Comment: This saved me some hair. Also, I'd love to know if you've managed to find an even better way since you posted this. Thanks :)

Comment: I get: `The method getCookieStore() is undefined for the type HttpClient`

Comment: Note that it's a `DefaultHttpClient`

Answer (score 23):

`CookieManager` is used by the Java's internal HTTP client. It has nothing to do with Apache HttpClient.

In your code you always create for each request a new instance of `HttpClient` and therefore a new `CookieStore` instance, which obviously gets garbage collected along with all cookies stored in as soon as that `HttpClient` instance goes out of scope.

You should either

(1) **Re-use the same instance of `HttpClient`** for all logically related HTTP requests and share it between all logically related threads (which is the recommended way of using Apache HttpClient)

(2) or, at the very least, **share the same instance of `CookieStore`** between logically related threads

(3) or, if you insist on using `CookieManager` to store all your cookies, **create a custom `CookieStore` implementation backed by `CookieManager`**

Comment: I specifically wanted to be able to pass only what is needed around my application (Although, example code on /how/ to pass this around would be well received). In this case the only thing that i needed in each `Activity` is the `Cookie`. The recommended approach to using `Cookies` across Activities (and also inter-process from what i've read) is to use the `CookieManager` which is why I wanted to use it to both save, view and then reuse `Cookies` inside of it. I will post my own solution to this problem ASAP and hopefully have any weaknesses in it explained.

Comment: I will also look into changing this code to use Java's internal `HttpClient` and post the solution along with any advantages i see in it.

Comment: This answer is just awesome

Comment: Thank you for comparing "recommended approaches" with "custom approaches".

Comment: I'm developing a brand new android app and will use your first approach - share the same HttpClient. Will have a static HttpClient on a custom BaseActivity and all my activities will extend BaseActivity. This way I have the same HttpClient for all screens. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In my application server wants to use same session with same cookies... 
After few hours of "googling" and painful headache I just saved cookies to SharedPreference or just put in some object and set DefaultHttpClient with same cookies again ... onDestroy just remove SharedPreferences ... that's all:

1. First copy SerializableCookie class to your package:
   [SerializableCookie](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27512913/SeriCookie.java)

Look the following example:

```
public class NodeServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private DefaultHttpClient client;


protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(nameValuePair);
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
        List<Cookie> cookies = loadSharedPreferencesCookie();
        if (cookies!=null){
            CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
            for (int i=0; i<cookies.size(); i++)
                cookieStore.addCookie(cookies.get(i));
            client.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
        }
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();

        saveSharedPreferencesCookies(cookies);
```

// two methods to save and load cookies ...

```
 private void saveSharedPreferencesCookies(List<Cookie> cookies) {
    SerializableCookie[] serializableCookies = new SerializableCookie[cookies.size()];
    for (int i=0;i<cookies.size();i++){
        SerializableCookie serializableCookie = new SerializableCookie(cookies.get(i));
        serializableCookies[i] = serializableCookie;
    }
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutput;
    ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(arrayOutputStream);


        objectOutput.writeObject(serializableCookies);
        byte[] data = arrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        objectOutput.close();
        arrayOutputStream.close();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream b64 = new Base64OutputStream(out, Base64.DEFAULT);
        b64.write(data);
        b64.close();
        out.close();

        editor.putString("cookies", new String(out.toByteArray()));
        editor.apply();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private List<Cookie> loadSharedPreferencesCookie() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    byte[] bytes = preferences.getString("cookies", "{}").getBytes();
    if (bytes.length == 0 || bytes.length==2)
        return null;
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    Base64InputStream base64InputStream = new Base64InputStream(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    ObjectInputStream in;
    List<Cookie> cookies = new ArrayList<Cookie>();
    SerializableCookie[] serializableCookies;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(base64InputStream);
        serializableCookies = (SerializableCookie[]) in.readObject();
        for (int i=0;i<serializableCookies.length; i++){
            Cookie cookie = serializableCookies[i].getCookie();
            cookies.add(cookie);
        }
        return cookies;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Google Luck

Comment: Where is SerializableCoockie.class file

Comment: I am not getting file. Please send me the Link for it. I really need it.

Comment: You can download the SerializableCoockie.class from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27512913/SeriCookie.java)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Since I am using Volley and not HTTPClient directly the Singleton for HTTPClient didn't seem like the correct solution. But using that same idea I simply saved the CookieManager in my application singleton.
So if app is my application singleton then in the onCreate() of each activity I add this:

```
    if (app.cookieManager == null) {
        app.cookieManager = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    }
    CookieHandler.setDefault(app.cookieManager);
```

To make this even better, all of my activities are subclasses of MyAppActivity so all I have to do is put it in the onCreate for MyAppActivity and then all of my activities inherit this functionality. Now all my activities are using the same cookie manager and my web service session is shared by all the activities. Simple and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose one of best thing is apply Singleton Pattern to your HTTPClient so you just have only one instance!

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class myHttpClient {
    private static HttpClient mClient;
    private myHttpClient() {};
    public static HttpClient getInstance() {
        if(mClient==null)
            mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        return mClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: Asynchronous request can not be done with single instance of HttpClient class

Answer (score -1):

A good solution for the cookie storage would be to follow the ThreadLocal pattern in order to avoid storing cookies randomly.

This will help keeping a one and only CookieStore. For more explanation of this pattern, you can follow this useful link.

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/11/java-thread-local-how-to-use-and-code-sample/

Cheers