# Get Cookies & Session and set again using HttpClient

Tags: java, swing, file-upload, httpclient

Hey guys i have a situation here...

Im working on a java program where my client want to login to a website with the given credentials and then upload a file to an url of the same website... The problem is either the client done know whether the user login is authenticated and set using cookie or session..

Im using HttpClient for both login and upload and i finished writing the code.. The problem is when upload a file i get "403 Forbidden". Is there a way to get the list of cookies and sessions so that i can fetch it from login url output and set it to upload as to think that the request is from an authenticated user.

For more reference im attaching the script:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;

public class Main {

    Header[] cookie = null;

    public void sendLoginRequest() {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/login");

            MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            mpEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody("user@website.com"));
            mpEntity.addPart("password", new StringBody("123456"));

            httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
            System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            if (resEntity != null) {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
            if (resEntity != null) {
                resEntity.consumeContent();
            }

            cookie = (Header[]) response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie");
            for(int h=0; h<cookie.length; h++){
                System.out.println(cookie[h]);
            }

            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

            sendFileRequest();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void sendFileRequest(){
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/uploadpage");
            httppost.setHeaders(cookie);

            File file = new File("somefile.jpg");

            MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
            ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
            mpEntity.addPart("Filedata", cbFile);
            mpEntity.addPart("MAX_FILE_SIZE", new StringBody("268435456"));

            httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
            System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            if (resEntity != null) {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
            if (resEntity != null) {
                resEntity.consumeContent();
            }

            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().sendLoginRequest();
    }
}
```

I need to show the upload page that the user is logged in so that it can upload...

Thank you...

Comment: Have a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802595/using-cookies-across-activities-when-using-httpclient