# need to store Caches an Cookies up to ending a session

Tags: java, android

How can we keep caches and cookies in native app up to completing a session (example booking tickets) in Retrofit(or other rest calls).

Ex. while booking tickets online, we will keep session up to last step of the process. I need to keep my session in a native app up to the last step of a similar process.

Comment: Try to use SharedPrefrences. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: shared preference is not a complete solution for my app.do you know any library for keeping session.

Comment: read this may be this will help you out. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416712/android-session-cookies

Comment: Thanks for your replay, this is the way now i am using its slow comparing other rest calls. so that i am searching new way .

Comment: https://github.com/datatheorem/HandlingCaching-Android