# store and get cookies for the code using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android

I am not getting how to store and get back cookies and  checked with example programs also in this code I am trying to login with a url with username and pass credentials  after that getting redirected to new page. I am trying to get the HTml content of the redirected page. But I need to pass the cookie to jsoup inorder to get the HTml content of the redirected page. I dont to store and get back cookies. Plz help me with code how to store and get back the cookies and pass it to the jsoup.

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
 old URL--->URL url = new URL(UrlLink);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            List<NameValuePair> login = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "xxxxx"));
            login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "yyyyyy"));
            login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Login", "Login"));
            login.clear();
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(responseCode);
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
New Url---> URL newURL = urlConnection.getURL();
            String urlNew=   newURL.toString();
Returns--> doc=Jsoup.connect(res).data("login", "xxxxxxx")
            .data("password", "ramesh88").get();
Login page  Elements docEle = doc.select("#header a");
 HTML       Log.v("Document", docEle.toString() );
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Error", e.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following links would be helpful:

[HOW-TO: Handling cookies using the java.net.* API](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html)

[How to handle cookies in httpUrlConnection using cookieManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150089/how-to-handle-cookies-in-httpurlconnection-using-cookiemanager)

Cheers !!