# Android HttpUrlConnection w Persistent Connection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, persistent-connection

**Scenario**

Users have to login to the server with this app. Later in the app we need to check their login status against the server. We used to do this by keeping track of the last used `HttpClient`. Recently we switched to `HttpUrlConnection` but the so-called *persistent connections* are not working.

**Question**

I wrote this test app to see if the connections were persistent. I get xml back from both URLs but the connection is not behaving like it's consistent. How can I get this to work?

Note: Everything works as expected if you go to the *Login* url in a browser and then go to the `GetUserInfo` url in the same browser.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mediajackagency.test;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button signInBtn = null;
    public Button getUserInfoBtn = null;
    public TextView xmlTextView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        this.xmlTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xmlTxtView);

        this.signInBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signInBtn);
        this.signInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                        String xml = loadUrl("https://www.fake.site/Login?userName=test&password=pass123");

                        return xml;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                        super.onPostExecute(o);
                        xmlTextView.setText(o.toString());
                    }
                };
                task.execute();
            }
        });

        this.getUserInfoBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getUserInfoBtn);
        this.getUserInfoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
                        String xml = loadUrl("https://www.fake.site/GetCurrentUser");

                        return xml;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                        super.onPostExecute(o);
                        xmlTextView.setText(o.toString());
                    }
                };
                task.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public String loadUrl(String url) {
        URI uri = MainActivity.encodeUrl(url);
        Log.i("XMLParser", "Get URL: " + url);

        String xml = null;
        URL link;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            link = new URL(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            is = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\r");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    if(reader != null) reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    if(is != null) is.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    if(connection != null) connection.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            xml = stringBuilder.toString();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xml;
    }

    public static URI encodeUrl(String url) {
        URL urlObject;
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            urlObject = new URL(url);
            uri = new URI(urlObject.getProtocol(), urlObject.getUserInfo(), urlObject.getHost(),
                    urlObject.getPort(), urlObject.getPath(), urlObject.getQuery(), urlObject.getRef());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return uri;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a lot of noise in your code example. it all boils down to leaving the connection open (there is no finally block after your try statement), and fundamentally that you really want to have a http authorized resource accessible during the lifetime of the application. this question could do well from removing all the unimportant ideas, and clean up the comments. it's a great question! though, very ugly to read ;) cheers

Comment: remove package/imports. replace catch's {e.printStackTrace();} with catch (XException ignored){}, remove log statements, remove comments that don't pertain to the question, and finally, add comments that do pertain to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved With Cookies

After days / hours of working on this I found that persistent connections (`http.keepalive`) with `HttpUrlConnection` is not all it's cracked up to be:

1) You need to make sure the `InputStream` and `HttpUrlConnection` are closed before you can reuse the connection and *even then* it may not always be reusable.

2) Open TCP connections can be resource hogs.

After finding & testing the idea of [using cookies with HttpUrlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150089/how-to-handle-cookies-in-httpurlconnection-using-cookiemanager) I decided to go that route as it's fundamentally more sound and performs better than my original idea.