# What is the significance of "ORA_BIPS_NQID" cookie and how to retrieve it from HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, httpurlconnection

I came across a new cookie while retrieving response from  `HttpURLConnection` name `ORA_BIPS_NQID`. What does this cookie refer to in a web application ?

How would I get the value of the cookie from my connection object?

Comment: According to [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2446090?tstart=0) Oracle community thread, the *ORA_BIPS_NQID* refers to the OBIEE 11g presentation service configuration. In order to retrieve the cookies from your connection object, take a look at [this](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html) documentation and at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171708/1346996) SO answer.

Comment: The link for the retrieving cookie is for getting the responses header . I tried but, I don't find any cookie with the 'ORA_BIPS_NQID' cookie name .