# Send a post login from java code and get cookie authentication

Tags: java, cookies, ssl-certificate, httpconnection

I need to login to an IIS web-server.

After login, I need to send an HTTP Post with a lot of data.

However, I don't know how to save my cookies from login and reuse them for subsequent HTTP calls.

### My code

```
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HttpURLConnectionExample.class);

private static final String CERTIFICATE_CLIENT = "/src/main/resources/clientcert.jks";
private static final String JAVAX_NET_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD = "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword";
private static final String JAVAX_NET_SSL_KEY_STORE = "javax.net.ssl.keyStore";
private static PropertiesManagement management;
private static final String LOGIN_PAGE = "https://alloggiatiweb.poliziadistato.it/Alloggiatiweb/Login.aspx";
private static final String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";
private static CookieManager msCookieManager = new CookieManager();
private static final String INTERNAL_PAGE = "https://alloggiatiweb.poliziadistato.it/Alloggiatiweb/Analisi.aspx";
private HttpsURLConnection conn;

private static void setCertificateSSL() throws FileNotFoundException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(management.getFilePath());
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(management.getSSLProtocol());
    ks.load(fin, management.getPassword().toCharArray());
    System.setProperty(JAVAX_NET_SSL_KEY_STORE, CERTIFICATE_CLIENT);
    System.setProperty(JAVAX_NET_SSL_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD, management.getPassword());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    management = new PropertiesManagement();
    setCertificateSSL();
    HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();
    http.login();
}

private void getInternalPage() throws Exception {
    URL obj = new URL(INTERNAL_PAGE);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    logger.info("[GET ON " + obj + " RESPONSE CODE-MESSAGE]" + conn.getResponseCode() + " - " + conn.getResponseMessage());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    logger.info(response.toString());
}

private void login() throws Exception {
    URL obj = new URL(LOGIN_PAGE);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtUtente", management.getUsername()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtPwd", management.getPassword()));

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(getQuery(params));
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    conn.connect();
    Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = conn.getHeaderFields();
    List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get(COOKIES_HEADER);
    if (cookiesHeader != null) {
        for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
            msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
        }
    }
    logger.info("[POST ON " + obj + " RESPONSE CODE-MESSAGE]" + conn.getResponseCode() + " - " + conn.getResponseMessage());
    getInternalPage();
    conn.disconnect();
}

private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

and this is response

```
 INFO (HttpURLConnectionExample.java:125) [19 apr 2016 15:08:51,013] - [POST ON https://alloggiatiweb.poliziadistato.it/Alloggiatiweb/Login.aspx RESPONSE CODE-MESSAGE]200 - OK
 INFO (HttpURLConnectionExample.java:83) [19 apr 2016 15:08:51,461] - [GET ON https://alloggiatiweb.poliziadistato.it/Alloggiatiweb/Analisi.aspx RESPONSE CODE-MESSAGE]200 - OK
 INFO (HttpURLConnectionExample.java:94) [19 apr 2016 15:08:51,464] - <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transit
.....
```

but the page print aren't internal page but it's login page

Comment: Hello! I have cleaned up your post a little bit. Your question is quite difficult to answer right now because it isn't obvious what you are attempting to ask. You need to clarify why you can't get the cookie data and why you can't post more information. For example, do you get an error message? If so, you need to post that with your question.

Comment: i have edit, i hope now it's more clear!

Comment: 302 indicates an HTTP redirection. You need to send another HTTP call to the URL indicated in the `location` header.

Comment: infact i try to connect to another page (site/private.aspx), or i don't understand what you mean...

Comment: You are sending your request to `https://alloggiatiweb.poliziadistato.it/Alloggiatiweb/Analisi.aspx` according to your log. Which results in a 302 that your server wants you to redirect to.

Comment: And it's correct, i want to send a GET to that's page, but server answer me "redirect to login". I suppose that's why i can't login at the server... but in the previous method i send a post e server response 200... i don't understand...

Comment: When I check that page in my browser, it complains about a missing certificate. You will likely need to use a valid certificate in your code to be able to access their server.

Comment: i use a valid certificate, in browser and in my code. I edit the main page with the code from import and use certificate!!!

Comment: Are you saving cookies for future use? Since you are using basic `HttpsURLConnection` it will not handle that for you. You need to take the cookies header you receive from your login call, and send those with your subsequent calls.

Comment: Tha's problem...i don't know how to save cookie :D

Comment: In that case, you would probably be better served by searching the Stack Overflow already answered database: [this would probably work for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171708/503508)

Comment: thanks, I'll try that solution... I used wrong keywords in the previous searching :-)

Comment: doesn't work for me, I'm confused...
P.S. cookiesHeader is empty....