# How to add cookie to url using HttpUrlConnection class in android?

Tags: android, json, cookies

I'm trying to parse the json data from an url, when i try to create connection , it throws the exception as 
**java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write request body after response has been read**

I got the response message as **Not found**.

and i checked the url in web browser it shows the Json data when i login wuth my credentials.

so, i found that i need to add the cookie to my connection, but i don't know how to do this.

```
    public void parseData(String cookie){
    HttpUrlConnection connection;

    try{
    URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
                    Log.e(TAG, "cookie " + cookie);

                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                    connection.connect();
Log.e(TAG,connection.getResponseMessage());

    /**
    here i'm trying to parse the data 
    using BufferedReader calss
    **/

    }
    catch(IOException e){}
    }
```

i need to add the cookie in connection.
Please help me on this.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16171708/4310784

Comment: i tried that way too. but i got an exception as "java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write request body after response has been read" can you tell me why it throws this exception. @Mohammad Z

Comment: @Madhan: Sorry, removed my answer as I realised I was wrong.

Answer (score 9):

According to [this link](http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html)
 you can do this:

> Values must be set prior to calling the connect method:

```
URL myUrl = new URL("http://www.hccp.org/cookieTest.jsp"); 
URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();
```

> Create a cookie string:

```
String myCookie = "userId=igbrown";
```

> Add the cookie to a request: Using the
>   setRequestProperty(String name, String value); method, we will add a
>   property named "Cookie", passing the cookie string created in the
>   previous step as the property value.

```
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", myCookie);
```

> Send the cookie to the server: To send the cookie, simply call connect() on the URLConnection
>   for which we have added the cookie property:

```
urlConn.connect()
```

Comment: actually i'm doing the same as your answer but it throws an exception i mention in my question  and the response code as 404 .

Comment: And if you want to add more than 1 cookie you can separate them by semicolons, e. g.: `String myCookie = "userId=igbrown;anyOther=345345";`