# Maintaining session across http calls in Android

Tags: java, android, apache, session

In my Android Project I was using old apache library for networking operations. There I used the **BasicCookie()** in HttpContext for maintaining sessions across the https calls. Now Google has deprecated the Apache Library and So I switched to URLConnection for networking. But I am not sure how I can set cookie in HttpsUrlConnection to maintain the session across the https calls. How can I set the same functionality in HttpURlConnection also.

I tried all these from this post, but didnt help.
[How to handle cookies in httpUrlConnection using cookieManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150089/how-to-handle-cookies-in-httpurlconnection-using-cookiemanager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a CookieManager member object in your Authentication class so you can access it from other Activities when you want to retrieve and use your cookie later.

```
//In MyAuthentication class
static CookieManager mCookieManager = new CookieManager();
static String COOKIE_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";

//authentication code 
//...

int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){                
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
    List<String> cookies = headers.get(COOKIE_HEADER);

    for(String cookie: cookies){
        HttpCookie httpCookie = HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0);
        mCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, httpCookie);
    }
}
```

In your other Activity where you want to set the retrieved cookie in your post request.

```
CookieManger cookieManager = MyAuthentication.mCookieManager;

//authentication code
//...
if(mCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0) {
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",
    TextUtils.join(";", mCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
}
```